# Apply CSS on matching text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to apply a class where text matches with `sibling` elements.

My certain condition is:

> I have a table with multiple rows based on data that I get through database.
>   One of the `td` elements has my defined class. 
>   Now I wanted to apply a class only on those `td` elements where the text of this element matches with another one.

So It would be like, td's whose `html/text` is equal has that class.

**I tried:**

```
$('#table tbody>tr').find('td[class^="customtd"]').each(function() {
    if($(this).html().trim() == $(this).siblings('td').html().trim()) {
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }else {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have to iterate each sibling `td` (or use `filter`), check for a text match, then add the class:

```
$('#table tbody>tr').find('td[class^="customtd"]').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    $(this).siblings("td").filter(function() {
        return $(this).text() == text;
    }).addClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the value you are searching for and then loop through all table data. If you find a match, add the certain class.

Furthermore you should cache variables in jQuery and avoid using each() function since its performance is really bad compared to for loops.

```
//cache the element you are searching for
var search = $('.customtd').html().trim();
//cache the whole table so we can use a for loop
var table = $('#table tbody>tr>td');

//use for loop for more performance
for (var i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
    if(table.eq(i).html().trim() == search) {
        table.eq(i).addClass('active');
    }else {
        table.eq(i).removeClass('active');
    }
}
```

Here is a working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/jnh2heuh/2/